# AS3: Conditional statement with a non-boolean variable as the condition

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-statements

I've seen conditional statements where the condition is just a variable, which is not a boolean variable. The variable is for an object.

```
if (myVariable) {
  doThis();
}
```

It seems to be checking if myVariable is null or not. Is that all it is doing? Is this good programming practice? Wouldn't it be better to do this?

```
if (myVariable != null) {
  doThis();
}
```

It seems much clearer that way.

Comment: It's totally fine either way except for functions where that type of object must be explicitly checked against null if(myfunction != null)

Comment: @BotMaster - You'll just get a compiler warning if doing it with a function (because the compiler will think you left out the () by accident) it will still compile and work.  But it's certainly more readable in my opinion to check functions explicitly

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote... it may be something many programmers take for granted, but it's a valid quetion

Comment: whatever you choose, in programming consistency is always preferred. So if you evaluate boolean like this if(myboolean == true) then you might as well do it for everything too. If you don't, then you might as well do the same for anything that can be evaluated that way. A boolean and the default type of complex object (null) are both evaluated in an if conditional so it would be inconsistent to do it one way for one and another way for the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To properly answer your question:

Using an if statement with an object like that, will check if the object exists.

So if object is `null` or `undefined` it will evaluate to the equivalent of `false` otherwise it will be the equivalent of `true`.

As far as "good programming practice" goes, that is very opinion based and best left out of StackOverflow.

There is no performance hit and you will find it very common in ECMAScript based languages (like AS3 and JS) - However, many stricter languages (like C# for instance) require an explicit Boolean check so if you program in multiple languages you may find it easier to be consistent.

It's entirely up to you!

Here are some additional examples you may want to consider:

```
var str:String;
if(str) //will evaluate as false as str is null/undefined

if(str = "myValue") //will evaluate true, as it will use the new assigned value of the var and you're allowed to assign values inside an if condition (though it's ugly and typically uneccessary)

var num:Number;

if(num) //will evaluate as false

num = 1;
if(num) //will evaluate as true

num = 0;
if(num) //will evaluate as false since num is 0

num = -1;
if(num) //will evaluate as true

var obj:Object
if(obj) //will evaluate false

obj = {};
if(obj) //will evaluate true (even though the object is empty, it exists)

var func:Function;
if(func) //false

func = function(){};
if(func) //true - the function exists

function foo():Boolean { return false; }
if(foo) //true - the function exists

if(foo()) //false, the return of the function is false

function foo1():void { return; };
if(foo1()) //false as there is no return type
```

Comment: second if is an assignment and will generate compiler warning.

Comment: @botMaster Indeed.  But some people like using assignments in if statements so i included it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myVariable) // fine but not really explicit.
```

I usually use:

```
if (myVariable !== null) // more readable to me
```

Comment: If it's more readable then I'm assuming you do this for boolean as well: if(myboolean == true) if not then it's not less or more readable.